# how to align multiple checkbox on the right of a text a with some amount of spacing so that each checkbox aligns vertically downwards on each text

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <h3> Faculty of Engineering <br> <h5>(Select the prefered programme by checking the box)</h5> </h3>
  <label> 1. Bachelor of Science in Telecommunications Engineering </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="BTE"> </input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label> 2. Bachelor of Science in Telecommunications Engineering (Top Up) </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="BTE_topup)"> </input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label> 3. Bachelor of Science in Computer Engineering </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="BCE"> </input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label> 4. Diploma in Telecommunications Engineering </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="DTE"> </input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label> 5. Certificate in Telecommunications Engineering </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CTE"> </input>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: As of this moment right now, you are missing your code.  Please add it soon before this question gets down-voted.  [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You would have to wrap each `label` + `input` pair in their own element and use an appropriate layout method.

I'd use **CSS Tables**

```css
div {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3> Faculty of Engineering <br> <h5>(Select the prefered programme by checking the box)</h5> </h3>
  <div class="row">
    <label>1. Bachelor of Science in Telecommunications Engineering</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="BTE" />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label>2. Bachelor of Science in Telecommunications Engineering (Top Up)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="BTE_topup)" />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label>3. Bachelor of Science in Computer Engineering</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="BCE" />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label>4. Diploma in Telecommunications Engineering</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="DTE" />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label>5. Certificate in Telecommunications Engineering</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CTE" />
  </div>

</div>
```